# keypress and keydown in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

```js
$(document).keydown(function(event){
    console.log('keydown function called: ' + event.which);
});
```

With the above code it only displays the key down 2 times when I press the same key in succession.  If I alternate between 2 different characters (or just type different characters) then it displays them all.  With keypress it's worse; it only displays the first press and nothing thereafter when I repeat pressing the same key.

The about box for Firefox says 34.0, Windows 7.

Is there some workaround I can use?

Comment: Looking at Firebug console?

Comment: Maybe it shows a number on the left of the log with how many times it was called, like in Chrome. If not, for a workaround, use Chrome...

Comment: Have a look at keyup function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When output repeats in console usually you have an indicator with the number of iterations. To avoid that you can add something unique to output. Here is an example with timestamp:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event){
    console.log('keydown function called: ' + event.which + ' ' + event.timeStamp);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using .bind for this. Also, depending on the browser it might not show every console.log when it's triggered by the same function. Use Google Chrome and it will just show you're message once but increment the number of times it was fired.

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function() {

    //do whatever

});
```